# Trying to display text in python

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.7

I am trying to display text with pygame
Here is the code:

```
pygame.font.init()
    myFont = pygame.font.get_default_font()
    text1 = "Welcome to tetris"
    text = myFont.render(text1, True, (255,255,255))
    screen.blit(text, (250, 350))
    pygame.display.update()
```

But the only thing it outputs is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tetris.py", line 17, in <module>
    text = myFont.render(text1, True, (255,255,255))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'render'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that `get_default_font` returns the name of a font rather than an actual font object.

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-display-text-to-pygame-window/

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved the problem myself. The get_default_font() function only returned the name of the font. I just used the filename of default font and created a font object.